# What does "A&E" mean in the context of a hospital?

Tags: meaning, british-english

This is the hospital where Boris Johnson has spent his second night in intensive care. What does "A&E" mean?

[image: St Thomas' Hospital]

Comment: You could easily have found that out by looking on the Internet.

Comment: I checked some online dictionaries.  Wiktionary has A&E, but dictionary.com defines it as "arts and entertainment"

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/a-and-e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Accident and Emergency"

It is the equivalent of American "ER", it is also called the "Casualty" department.

It is the part of the hospital that takes serious and unplanned admissions.  (Normally in Britain you don't go to a hospital in the first instance, you see a GP (general practitioner) in their clinic, not in a hospital.  You are then referred to hospital for further treatment.  But for emergencies, like car crash victims, the ambulance takes you direct to A&E in the hospital)